# How to make ajax show table list without clicking the text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created a live search using ajax and it worked perfectly well. However the problem is that I need to click the input field first to show all the listed data. The reason for this may be the `keyup` function. I don't know what to replace that. I did tried to change to focus and so on but then ajax not showing my data at all. I am not familiar with ajax.

Here is my input code and ajax.

```
<p style="text-align: center">Enter your search here: <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Enter your search here">&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><i>ex: d1234567891.. hazwan.. etc.. </i></b></p>
<div id="result" class="login"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#search").keyup(function() {
            $("#result").show();
            var x = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'res.php',
                data:'q='+x,
                cache:false,
                success:function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data)
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</div>
```

and here is my database code and display result.

```
//print_r($_GET);
$q=$_POST['q'];
$query="SELECT *
            FROM
                viewlibrary
            WHERE 
                studentname LIKE :q OR
                matricno LIKE :q OR
                title LIKE :q OR
                programme LIKE :q OR
                serialno LIKE :q
            ORDER BY studentname ASC";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bindValue(':q','%'.$q.'%');
$stmt->execute();

$a = 0; 

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    $r=$stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<table class='tablesorter' id='myTable' style='width:97%; table-border: 1'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>No.</th>";
        echo "<th>No.Matric</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Programme</th>";
        echo "<th>Title</th>";
        echo "<th>Serial Number</th>";
        echo "<th>Availability</th>";
        echo "<th>Edit</th>";
        echo "<th>Delete</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

    foreach($r as $row){

            echo "<tr align='center'><td>". ($a+1) ."</td><td>". $row['matricno'] ."</td><td>". $row['studentname'] ."</td><td>". $row['programme'] ."</td><td>". $row['title'] ."</td><td>". $row['serialno'] ."</td><td>". $row['bavailable'] ."</td><td><a href='editpage.php?idstudent=".$row['matricno']."&idbook=".$row['serialno']."'><img src='pic/edit-icon.png' width=15px></a></td><td><a href='deletepage.php?idstudent=".$row['matricno']."&idbook=".$row['serialno']."'><img src='pic/remove-icon-png-15.png' width=15px></a></td></tr>";
            $a++;
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
else{
    echo "<p align='center'>Nothing to show you :( I am really sorry for this T_T </p>";
}
?>
```

The thing everytime I do some editing towards ajax code, its not running anymore. I try looking on the internet but can't find one suitable with ajax.
So what I want actually is to show all data listed when the page loaded and not after the user click the input field.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried moving the ajax to a separate function?

Ex.

```
function ajaxSearchUpdater(){
    $("#result").show();
    var x = $('#search').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'res.php',
        data:'q='+x,
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html(data)
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    ajaxSearchUpdater();               // fires on document.ready
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        ajaxSearchUpdater();           // your function call
    }
}
```